# Alternative to Ruby Case statement

Tags: ruby, switch-statement

I am currently writing a program for a banking administration system using Ruby. One of the capabilities of this system is that it can create a new account, accounts can be one of six types.

**I have the following method in my controller to cater for this function:**

```
def create_account(type, holder)
  case type
  when :current  then CurrentAccount.new(holder, @account_number)
  when :savings  then SavingsAccount.new(holder, @account_number)
  when :business then BusinessAccount.new(holder, @account_number)
  when :ir       then IRAccount.new(holder, @account_number)
  when :smb      then SMBAccount.new(holder, @account_number)
  when :student  then StudentAccount.new(holder, @account_number)
  end
end
```

Each of these accounts inherits from a base account and will eventually contain individual attributes, e.g. Interest rate, overdraft, etc.

Although this is functional and delivers the required results it feels a bit lengthy. However I can't think of any obvious ways to refactor.

Any suggestions welcome...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am assuming that at some point the system or end user is effectively selecting a text type and you need to convert that into a class to use. Otherwise you could write calling code that simply referred and instantiated the correct class.

You can make what you have cleaner by defining a mapping between the symbol `type` and the class. So you could do this in the scope of `create_account`:

```
ACCOUNT_CLASS_FOR = Hash[
  current:  CurrentAccount,
  savings:  SavingsAccount,
  business: BusinessAccount,
  ir:       IRAccount,
  smb:      SMBAccount,
  student:  StudentAccount
]

def create_account(type, holder)
  if account_class = ACCOUNT_CLASS_FOR[ type ]
    account_class.new( holder, @account_number )
  else
    raise "Bad account type #{type}"
  end
end
```

This has less repeated code, and makes the mapping between the symbol names and matching Ruby classes more explicit. If you need to apply or test the conversion elsewhere, you could make the constant available in a different scope without repeating yourself.

You can make this even cleaner by having each class know its own label e.g.

```
class CurrentAccount
  def self.label
     :current
  end
end
```

Then you could have something like this:

```
ALLOWED_ACCOUNT_CLASSES = [CurrentAccount,SavingsAccount,BusinessAccount, # etc.

ACCOUNT_CLASS_FOR = Hash[
  ALLOWED_ACCOUNT_CLASSES.map { |klass| [klass.label, klass] }
]
```

Note it's quite common practice to use the mis-spelled `klass` variable here to avoid clashing with Ruby's `class` keyword, but you could also just use `account_class`

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way, but you would need the type to be accordingly named with the class (ie.  :ir -> :i_r )

```
def create_account(type, holder)
    Object.const_get(type.to_s.camelize + "Account").new(holder, @account_number)
end
```

Even if this one is shorter, I like Neil answer because it looks safer

Comment: I would break this to two lines (one to store the class name in a variable, the next to instantiate it) and add error handling, but I prefer this to the accepted answer.